# Defining global behavior of a function? Good practice

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture

this question is of general nature. Suppose you have a lot of microservices calling some internal library. This library has a core function `core_function(arg_1,arg_2,..)`

In some cases the function should react a bit differently.
So what would be a good practice?

Some ideas that I have:

1. Add an argument to the function. `behavior_param`.
   Drawback: Many microservice should be refactored. The microservices are classes. So I would have to introduce a new parameter to each class
   (or at least a default parameter) and use it when calling the
   function (of course only to the microservices that need the modified behaviour)
2. Add some global variable in the library like 
   `behavior_param` maybe in the __init__ file. Drawback: I would have a global parameter and don't like that.
3. Using environment variables. It's like the second solution. But somehow I like that idea better

What do you think? Hope the question is clear. I'm searching for the best and most natural approach to this in python.

Comment: Behavior of other functions in lib are depnds from this param?

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct -- avoid using global variables to dynamically modify the behavior of `core_function`. Generally speaking, they will make your code harder for others to follow, harder to maintain and more fragile. Use them as an option of last resort.

If you want to modify the behavior of `core_function` without re-factoring all instances of where `core_function` is already invoked, then you should add an optional argument to `core_function` and supply a default value. This optional argument will dictate the "behavior mode" that  function should follow.

Change this:

```
def core_function(arg_1, arg_2):
```

To this:

```
def core_function(arg_1, arg_2, behavior_param = 'Default'):
```

This will allow your existing code to continue using `core_function` with the default behavior and without any re-factoring. For future code, you can supply the optional argument and specify the behavior that you want.

Comment: Yeah I see and use that quite often. In this case the core_function call is somewhere deep inside different classes. So somehow I don't like the Idea to pass the parameter down to the call. I would have to introduce one more parameter to some general classes (that is only needed in some special cases). On the other hand, it is definitely a clean solution.

Comment: @MichaelRazum Are you essentially trying to avoid bloating the constructor of those parent classes with extra parameters? If that's the case, you could define `behavior_param` as an attribute on those classes,  omit it from the constructor entirely, and add a helper method like `set_behavior` so that the attribute can be updated dynamically.

Comment: Yes exactly. Sound like a reasonable idea. Will think about it. Thanks a lot :)!!!

Answer (score 1):

Flags that alter behaviour, whether they are globals or function parameters are ok up to a point, but if they result in too much branching (`if`s) in the function code I prefer to have a group of functions, each one providing one of the desired behaviours, and a factory function that returns the right function based on the flag value.

This separates selecting the right behaviour from the implementation of the behaviour.

For example, something like this:

```
def factory(arg0, arg1 ..., flag):
   func_map = {
        0: func0,
        1: func1,
        2: func2
   }
   return func_map[flag](arg0, arg1)

result = factory(foo, bar, 1)
```

I wouldn't do this if there are just two possible behaviours, but would definitely consider for three or more.

Comment: What would you do if you had only two behaviors? I like this pattern!

Comment: For just two I could probably live with a flag variable (global or param) and an `if` inside the function.  My rule of thumb is basically the more `if`s (or `elif`s) I see in a function, the more I think it needs refactoring, though it always depends on the wider context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the above problem. Notice the solution with the default parameter is the standard way to go. This solution is helpful if there are multiple functions that should react to some default behaviour.

```
_default_behavior = { "arg_1": value_1, "arg_2": value_2}

def set_default_behavior(value_1, value_2):
   _default_behavior["arg_1"] = value_1
   _default_behavior["arg_2"] = value_2

def core_function():
   if _default_behavior["arg_1"] == True:
      # do some stuff and also arg_2 may be used
      pass 
   else: 
      # here is the default case
      pass
```